# Reactive power of a discharged capacitor

Tags: power, capacitor, power-engineering

I was wondering if a DISCHARGED capacitor connected to a grid gives to this one a positive reactive power. Is it yes? If not, it's true to say that only charged capacitors gives positive power to the grid? And my last question is: the capacitor banks connected to the grid are charged or dischaged?

Comment: Reactive power does not at all depend on the initial state of charge, except maybe in the first AC cycle. Remember the grid is AC : capacitors charge and discharge twice every cycle.

Comment: oh yes you are right! But if I have a DC grid (for example)?

Comment: Reactive power is an AC phenomenon. So if you have a DC grid there is no reactive power! The capacitor there is a reservoir to reduce voltage fluctuations under varying current demand.

Comment: Right!! Thank you very much sir!!!

Comment: @BrianDrummond I suggest you put your comments into an answer, (and that Samuele accepts it afterwards). That way people can see that it has been answered.